# MDADM lists same device twice

Tags: raid, mdadm, software-raid

I'm attempting to get a software RAID array going using [this guide][1].  I've worked my way through preparing the second disk (/dev/sdb) without any errors.

After running:

```
mkswap /dev/md5
```

I run:

```
mdadm --examine --scan
```

Before piping it to my /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf file.  Problem is, I seem to be getting two results for the same device:

```
root@test:~# mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/5 metadata=1.2 UUID=9985ef40:2eb8407d:c0a195b1:509136fe name=test:5
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=34de79db:470dce04:ece45660:b4af82d5 name=test:1
ARRAY /dev/md/5 metadata=1.2 UUID=27796750:70770c0a:f5af0aca:5367090e name=test:5
```

I am following [this tutorial](http://sysadmin.compxtreme.ro/how-to-migrate-a-single-disk-linux-system-to-software-raid1/).  The machine I'm testing on had a software RAID array on it before, but I ran mdadm --zero-superblock on both partitions to ensure any remnants were gone.

Any ideas as to why I'm getting two entries for the same disk?

Comment: try `mdadm --detail /dev/md*` or `--detail --scan`

Comment: So those two commands list the last two entries in my original command.  Is there a way to remove/delete the first one?  Thanks again for your help on this.

Comment: Hmmm, should be three. `mdadm -v --examine --scan` would list the devices.

Comment: Ok -- in looking at this, it appears as though the first /dev/md/5 device is pointing to /dev/sda5, which is probably my issue here.  Any idea how I disassociate /dev/md/5 from /dev/sda5?

Comment: If sda5 is not part of any raid, you can `mdadm --zero-superblock` it.

Comment: It's my primary swap partition, so I don't think mdadm is going to be able to open it for write...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/dev/md5` and `/dev/md/5` is not the same thing. You probably actually do have three arrays, only you ended up with the same name for two of them.

`/dev/md5` is a numbered md device, and `/dev/md/5` is a named one. Names are arbitrary, can be anything. You could make a `/dev/md/swap` if you so desire. You update it with `--update=name`, on creation it's the `--name=` option, or simply specifying `/dev/md/name` in the first place. The manpage describes this in some detail.

Personally I don't like md names very much. It's particularly pointless when you end up using some number as a name. You can stick with numbers in the first place then. If you want names, use descriptive ones (root, home, swap, ...).

In general, `mdadm --examine --scan` is just a starting point. You really only need the UUID so you could do something like this:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 UUID=9985ef40:2eb8407d:c0a195b1:509136fe
ARRAY /dev/md1 UUID=34de79db:470dce04:ece45660:b4af82d5
ARRAY /dev/md2 UUID=27796750:70770c0a:f5af0aca:5367090e
```

Don't forget to add a `MAILADDR` (and have a mdadm monitor service running).

Comment: Thanks for the reply -- how can you tell which one is the numbered and which is the named?  They're both listed as /dev/md/5 in my mdadm output...