# Conflict new disk with existed RAID

Tags: configuration, raid

I have a RAID 5 conf. file where 3 HDD create a RAID 5 array

```
ARRAY /dev/md127 level=raid5 num-devices=3 metadata=1.2 spares=1
name=ws5:127 UUID=db7a57f0:a8c9967b:06d09672:65559a58   
devices=/dev/sdd,/dev/sde,/dev/sdf
```

I added a new disk in the workstation and the current situation is the below:

```
sdd       8:48   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─md126   9:126  0  14.6T  0 raid5
sde       8:64   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─md126   9:126  0  14.6T  0 raid5
sdf       8:80   0   7.3T  0 disk
sdg       8:96   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─md126   9:126  0  14.6T  0 raid5
sdh       8:112  1     0B  0 disk
```

Before to add the disk, **sdf** was part of the RAID, but after adding the new disk sdf was assigned to the new disk, while part of the RAID become sdg.

I was thinking to change just the letter "sdf" with "sdg" in the configuration file just I do not know if I'm going to brake the RAID. Any safe solution?

Comment: for mdadm.conf, use `ARRAY /dev/mdX UUID=a:b:c:d` - just the UUID alone is enough to identify the array, device names and everything else may change. If you make mdadm.conf too verbose, it will be ignored and fall back to auto detection.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/703905/30851 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325519/30851 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533941/30851